# Prevent scaling on Kindle Paperwhite browser

Tags: javascript, kindle

I am trying to develop an app that works on the Kindle Paperwhite "experimental" browser. I would like to prevent the browser from scaling because I have designed my app to fit the screen perfectly.

I tried using:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,
      maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

But the browser seems to ignore the declaration.

There are two ways I find scaling happens: (1) when the user click on a text box. The whole screen is scaled up to make the textbox large. (2) when the user zooms the screen by pinching.

I tried hooking into touch events with the idea of cancelling them. But they are not fired.

Is there any other event I can use?

Comment: Have you considered simply allowing zooming? I find myself frustrated by sites that won't let me zoom, or won't zoom correctly.

Comment: Yes, of course I have and I agree. But the way it zooms is naive. It zooms automatically when you click on a textbox and makes it absolutely massive but it doesn't unzoom after you've entered text. You have to pinch to get back to how you were and it's not intuitive because you didn't do the zooming-in yourself.

Comment: Perhaps if you hook into the blur/focusout event and zoom out?